# What does linking against a framework mean? (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, frameworks, hyperlink

I am unclear as to what linking against a framework does and how to do it. It sounds like just weak linking the framework but I don't think it is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you read this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your project in XCode.  Look at the left column.  Control-Click on "frameworks".

Select "Add..." "Existing Frameworks".

Comment: Oh ok thanks! It would have been clearer if they had just said add a framework.